# programming, logic using gloabal variables

Tags: php, logic

lets say i have a function add().

```
function add(){
 if (a)
  return true;
 if (b)
  return true;
 if (c)
  insert into table. 
  return true;
 }
```

now i call this function add() and i want to increment my counter only if there is insert execution like condition C. I also don't want to change the return value which is true. Now my question is how can i find out if section C is executed?
I thought i can use a global variable in condition c like below

```
if (c)
{
 insert into table. 
 $added = true;
 return true;
}
```

and then i check

```
if(isset($added && $added==true))
$count++;
```

but i would like to know if there is any parameter i can add or some other approach i can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an if around your insert, and add a counter as a parameter:

```
$count = 0;
function add(&$count){
 if (a)
  return true;
 if (b)
  return true;
 if (c)
  if(insert into table){ //Queries return a boolean
    $count++;
  } 
  return true;
}

add($count); //If insertion was succesful it added 1 to counter.
echo $count; //Returns either 1 or 0 depending on insert statement.
```

Comment: i am calling this function which resides in another class. If add a parameter "$count" add($count) and the function returns true. Would i be able to access the right value of $count? and is the count variable gloabal?

Comment: @Shaonline Yes you will, that's why I added the & sign in the parameter. It lets you alter the variable inside the function, it's called a parameter by reference.

Comment: Sweeet... it worked, Thanks, But would required to change other places where this function has been called? i mean would that require to pass the reference variable in every call? by the way i set its default value to zero, so i guess it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a parameter *by reference*. In PHP, this is done by prepending a pound sign (`&`). The result is that your function doesn't get a copy of the value but a variable refering the original value, so you can change it inside your function.

```
function add(&$itemsAdded)
{
    $itemsAdded = 0;
    [...]
    /* if added something */
    $itemsAdded++;
}
```

in your calling code

```
add($added);
$counter += $added;
```

Comment: this function is called in many places would that effect other calling places? would i need to pass this parameter in every call? or can i make its default value to zero?